Encountering a Crash when I add in a zombie asset I coded in for Godot 4
I've been following a really quick tutorial by a guy named MizizizizTutorials about how to do a top down game. the vid is 17 minutes long, and i've pretty much followed everything to the letter. When I just have the player in everything works fine, but its when I add my Zombie asset that the whole game/debugger crashes.
im not exactly sure why its doing it. This is the code I've put in, and I've copied it line for line in the tutorial:
extends CharacterBody2D

@onready var ray_cast_2d = $RayCast2D

@export var move_speed = 100
@onready var player : CharacterBody2D = get_tree().get_first_node_in_group("player")

var dead = false

func _physics_process(_delta):
    if dead: 
        return
    
    var dir_to_player = global_position.direction_to(player.global_position)
    velocity = dir_to_player * move_speed
    move_and_slide()
    
    global_rotation = dir_to_player.angle() + PI/2.0
    
    if ray_cast_2d.is_colliding() and ray_cast_2d.get_collider() == player: 
        player.kill()
        
func kill():
    if dead:
        return
    dead = true
    $Deathsound.play()
    $Graphics/Dead.show()
    $Graphics/alive.hide()
    $CanvasLayer/DeathScreen.show()
    $CollisionShape2D.disabled = true
    z_index = -1 
    

Im a complete novice when it comes to coding with GDscript, and I have a small amount of knowledge in python.
When I run it there is a small yellow arrow pointing to this line of code:
   `var dir_to_player = global_position.direction_to(player.global_position)`

its also feeding me this error message:
            Invalid get index 'global_position' (on base: 'null instance') 

Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated.
